# How do I fix PyDev "Method should have self as first parameter" errors

Tags: python, code-analysis, pydev

I'm developing in Python using PyDev in Eclipse, and some of my code generates errors in the code analysis tool.  Specifically:

```
class Group(object):
    def key(self, k):
        class Subkey(object):
            def __enter__(s):
                self._settings.beginGroup(k)
                return self

            def __exit__(s, type, value, tb):
                self._settings.endGroup()

         return Subkey()
```

Gives me a `"Method '__enter__- group' should have self as first parameter"` error, and a similar error for `__exit__`.  Is there a way to solve this without assigning `self` to another variable and reusing the variable in the other method signatures?

Comment: If you're gonna use `s` instead of `self`, you have to use `s` everywhere. Be consistent!

Comment: I need a reference to the outer class self variable.  If I'm consistent, I shadow the outer class reference in the inner class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could disable that error in the preferences...

```
Window > Preferences > Pydev > Editor > Code Analysis > Others
```

Or refactor the code...

```
class Group(object):
    def key(self, k):
        outer_self = self
        class Subkey(object):
            def __enter__(self):
                outer_self._settings.beginGroup(k)
                return outer_self

            def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
                outer_self._settings.endGroup()

         return Subkey()
```

What else do you expect?  The error checks are there to help you.  If you don't think they're legitimate errors, disable them or refactor the code.

In this case I'd say refactor the code.  It's more readable, as evidenced by King Radical's answer.  He didn't understand that `s` was another `self`.

Comment: In my case I cannot add the self as first argument since flask will complain. I have this line def validate_phone_number(form, field): and once I change it to def validate_phone_number(self, form, field): I get the following error "TypeError: validate_phone_number() missing 1 required positional argument: 'field'"

Answer (score 18):

Using `Ctrl+1` in a line with an error from PyDev will always bring you a fix which will allow you to ignore the PyDev error in the line. In this specific case, it'll allow you to ignore the error by adding `#@NoSelf` to the end of the line. `Ctrl+1` is also useful when some unused import is needed and under other situations.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and should be accepted.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a decorator:

```
class aClass:
        def __init__(self):       # instance-dependent method
        self.atribite1 = []
        self.atribute2 = 0 

        @staticmethod   
        def static():             # static method
        pass
```

[The Built-in function used for this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be an error in the first place, as using "self" is only a widely-accepted convention. It should be a warning at most, in the sense of "are you sure you're using the class instance as the first argument?"

Answer (score 3):

IMO this is a silly warning. the *name* "self" is only convention. I got the habit of using the name "_" to allow the member names to be more obvious,

```
class myClass( object ):
    def __init__( _, color, shape, weight ):
        _.color=color
        _.shape=shape
        _.weight=weight
...
```

and I get this warning all over my library of thousands of lines of code. So I'll be switching this warning off. Would be nice to be able to specify "for this project I use '_' by convention"...

Comment: It's not *only* a convention.  Conventions are very important.  They save time and make communication easier to understand.  Basically, you deserve to be mercilessly harassed by every tool you use until you give up this pointlessly contrarian style :-).

Comment: if it were that important it should be a language warning or error. Either pydev or python is to blame here, not me... never me :-)

Answer (score 2):

PyDev is telling you that Python class methods must have `self` as the first variable they receive, if they're going to access the class member variables.  See: http://www.python.org/doc/faq/general/#why-must-self-be-used-explicitly-in-method-definitions-and-calls

Edit:  It didn't initially occur to me that you might be using `s` instead of `self`, but in view of the other answers, that may be.  However, if you're going to do that, you also need to use `s` as your variable in the method, rather than `self`.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what the code does.  This is a context manager defined within another class method.  So the inner class Subkey does, indeed, intend to call methods on the outer class Group's self variable.  And does not require a reference to its own instance variable.

Comment: @Chris B.:  That was not clear (at least to me) from the original question.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the code in the question. Good places to start would be learning about nested classes and lexical scope. It's also a good idea to try the code sample and figure out what it does before replying.

Comment: @GreenMatt The link you provided is now broken and I am struggling to find it... do you think you can find it?