# Where is app.sqlite located?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

Hi guys I've been following this old tutorial. Can someone tell me where app.sqlite will be located. Also is app.sqlite a database that I have made I'm not sure because I wanna wanna find it and checked if the table is made. Also is there a wayto change the location to where i want it :D

This is the config file.

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.sqlite')
SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO = os.path.join(basedir, 'db_repository')
```

And this is the file where I try to make RESTful API, I haven't put anything in yet though since I'm lost.

```
 from flask import Flask, jsonify
 from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.config.from_pyfile('Config.py')
 db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
   User_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   firstName = db.Column(db.String(20))
   lastName = db.Column(db.String(20))

def __init__(self,firstName, lastName):
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    db.createAll()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: print `basedir` and you see.

Comment: oh thanks, is there a reason why I can't seem to see the file though? it shows me the location but when I go there it's not there

Comment: maybe it doesn't create it yet. Or you have other problem - so run Flask in debug mode to see in browser every error.

Comment: shouldn't it give me an error though if it isn't

Comment: without debug mode it can show you only ie. "Error 500" without all information about problem.

Comment: eeek i find it tyty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place `app.sqlite` in the same directory as your main python file. To create all of the tables, you can add the following method to your code:

```
@app.before_first_request
def startup():
    db.create_all()
```

This will run when you start your server and will create all of the tables. If you restart the server, the method will still run, but the tables won't be remade since they already exist.

Comment: it tells me I have to put self inside the method.

Comment: You shouldn't have to, since your `db` isn't a part of an object. Can you paste the error here?

Comment: it says method must have a first parameter, usually called "self"

Comment: Oh, i added it at the bottom of the methods, now at the top it works.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If so, [it might be an error with Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112770/how-do-i-fix-pydev-method-should-have-self-as-first-parameter-errors). If not, where did you paste the method? It should be added right above `if __name__ == '__main__':`. 

Also, you should remove `db.createAll()` from your user `__init__` method, as this code stub replaces that.

Comment: I'm using pycharm. I put it below the method now and it's working buuuut, how can i check if table is made in database file? actually when I put it below the if __name__ == part it doesn't work for some reason. it only works when I put it right at the top after db = sqlalchemy(app) part and only when i open the server o.o

Comment: When you first create the file, it will be 0 bytes, since there is no data stored in it (no table schema, etc.). When the table is created, the file will be greater than 0 bytes.